# r create and address variable in for loop

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I have multiple csv-files in one folder. I want to load each csv-file in this folder into one separate data frame. Next, I want to extract certain elements from this data frame into a matrix and calculate the mean of all these matrixes.

```
setwd("D:\\data")
group_1<-list.files()
a<-length(group_1)

mferg_mean<-data.frame

for(i in 1:a)
{ 
assign(paste0("mferg_",i),read.csv(group_1[i],header=FALSE,sep=";",quote="",dec=",",col.names=1:90))
}
```

As there are 11 csv-files in the folder I now have the data frames

```
mferg_1
```

to

```
mferg_11
```

How can I address each data frame in this loop? As mentioned, I want to extract certain elements from each data frame to a matrix. I would imagine it something like this:

```
assign(paste0("mferg_matrix_",i),mferg_i[1:5,1:10])
```

But this obviously does not work because R does not recognize mferg_i in the loop. How can I address this data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something you should probably be using `assign` for in the first place. Working with a bunch of different data.frames in R is a mess, but working with a *list* of data.frames is much easier. Try reading your data with

```
group_1<-list.files()
mferg <- lapply(group_1, function(filename) { 
    read.csv(filename,header=FALSE,sep=";",quote="",dec=",",col.names=1:90))
})
```

and you get each each value with `mferg[[1]]`, `mferg[[1]]`, etc. And then you can create a list of extractions with

```
mferg_matrix <- lapply(mferg, function(x) x[1:5, 1:10])
```

This is the more R-like way to do things.

But technically you can use `get` to retrieve values like you use `assign` to create them. For example

```
assign(paste0("mferg_matrix_",i),get(paste0("mferg_",i))[1:5,1:10])
```

but again, this is probably not a smart strategy in the long run.

Comment: That´s incredible, it works but I do not understand why! Thank you! I got to spend the night decoding those few lines of yours!